# Return this inside Ajax call of JQuery plugin for chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I'm trying to chain several calls of a plugin I wrote. The plugin itself has two possible Ajax calls - to a content store service as well as to a handlebars template. I have caching on both, but on first load the order of the cards often changes due to some of the calls taking a little bit longer than their predecessors. As a result the order of the cards change which is problematic in terms of the content hierarchy. In this example, I am loading cards tagged as research and podcast.

I invoke the plugin as follows:

```
$('#research').getCards({
    category: 'research',
}).getCards({
    category: 'podcast'
});
```

The plugin is quite large, so I'm only posting the last Ajax call (which is where I want to return this). The fetchTemplate function is invoked once the data is fetched from my service, counter is 0 and length is the length of card_data when the function is initialised. I want this function to recurse until each item in my card_data array has a card printed, and then it should return this to allow the next call to getCards.

```
$.fn.getCards = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        target: this,
        category: '',
    },

    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    function fetchTemplate(card_data, counter, length) {
        counter++;
        var cardTemplate = '';

        if (localStorage[cardTemplate] && settings.localStorageSupport) {
            printCard(localStorage[cardTemplate], card_data[counter - 1]);
            if (counter !== length) {
                fetchTemplate(card_data, counter, length);
            }
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/templates/cards/' + cardTemplate + '.hbs.js',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    localStorage.setItem(cardTemplate, data);
                    printCard(data, card_data[counter - 1]);
                    return this // this is when I want to fire my chained call
                    if (counter !== length) {
                        fetchTemplate(card_data, counter, length);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

};
```

I have tried closures and this didn't work. I've also tried `return settings.target`. Lastly I've tried wrapping the whole plugin in `return this.each` but this didn't work as each fires before the Ajax request is completed. I know that I could potentially rewrite the plugin to call for an array of categories with only one call to getCards, but I'd prefer not to rewrite all my logic.

Comment: Maybe you can make your ajax calls synchronous. Also remember to return your current object inside of the $.fn.getCards function, not just the success function

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath this does work, but I often load cards dynamically using this same plugin. The service used for podcast is also sometimes unreliable and slow so page speed might suffer as a result.

Comment: `$.ajax()` returns results asynchronously. No value is returned from `.getCards()`

Comment: I would add return this;  as last line in your $.fn.getCards function.  Then as part of the options parameter, I would add ad object field called processNow: (true | false) .  Which if false, you can wait to call the $.fn.getCards function (again) like so:    if (counter !== length) {
                        fetchTemplate(card_data, counter, length);
                    } else {  $.fn.getCards(options) ...   }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()` and `.promise()` to perform asynchronous tasks in sequential order.

You set `context` of `$.ajax()` call to `this` within the method for `this` to be the element within `.then()`, define a property at `.data()` of `this` set to an array within the function and populate the array with results of asynchronous tasks. Set Chain `.then()` to get results from `$.fn.getCards()` call where `this` will be set to the original jQuery object and the results of the asynchronous tasks will be accessible at `.data()` of `this`. You can then call `.getCards()` again, repeat the procedure.

```js
$.fn.getCards = function(options) {
  var el = this;
  if (!this.data().results) {
    this.data().results = [];
  }
  return this.queue("cards", $.map(options, function(item) {
    return function(next) {
      return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          dfd.resolveWith(el, [item])
        }, 1000)
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        this.data().results.push(data);
        return;
      })
      .then(next)
    }
  })).dequeue("cards").promise("cards")
}

$("body")
.getCards([1,2,3])
.then(function() { 
  console.log(this.data().results, this.get(0).tagName === "BODY"); 
  return this.getCards([4,5,6])
})
.then(function() {
 console.log(this.data().results, this.get(0).tagName === "BODY");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give this a try, but would have to rewrite a big part of my plugin (suppose there's no way around it).